# Android JSON Object lost the Remaining Data From URL

Tags: android, mysql, json

I'm fetching a Stop record from my PHP MYSQL DB in the form of JSON and on receiving in Android JSON problem is that after 91 stops JSON object do not fetch further record i have 400+ DB record, Please any one help me why JSON Object not fetching a all records?

ANDROID CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DBProcessing().execute();

    }

    public class DBProcessing extends AsyncTask<String,Object,Object>
    {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
     String result=null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

           // DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
            String getURL = "http://192.168.1.51:80/StopViewApi/index.php";

            String GetStopid="";
            String Getstopname="";
            String Getstoplatitude="";
            String Getstoplongitude="";

            List<NameValuePair> pair = new ArrayList<>();
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Stop_id", GetStopid));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Stop_name", Getstopname));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Stop_latitude", Getstoplatitude));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Stop_longitude", Getstoplongitude));


            json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(getURL,"POST", pair);


           // Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            JSONObject jObject=null;

            try {




             //  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data=null;

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.toString());
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {

                        System.out.println("Stop_id:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Stop_id"));
                        System.out.println("Stop_name:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Stop_name"));
                        System.out.println("Stop_latitude:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Stop_latitude"));
                        System.out.println("Stop_longitude:"+array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Stop_longitude"));
                    }
                    Log.d("Record Found!", json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS));
                   // Log.d("Stop record:!", json.toString());
                    //Log.i("Stop_name:", Getstopname);
                    //Log.i("Stop_latitude",Getstoplatitude);
                    //Log.i("Stop_longitude",Getstoplongitude);

                }

                else if (success==0){

                    Log.d("Record Failure!", json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS));
                    return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

JSON URL

```
"success":1,"data":[["1","Pirwadhai Mor","33.615707","72.994629"],["2","Mandi Mor","33.634666","73.032005"],["3","Police Line","33.652676","73.013039"]
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting the URL through a browser/REST-client to check whether it is correctly sending json data ?

Comment: Yes i did its returning a full data properly but my Android end JSON just gets a 91 Stops data then stops..

Comment: Do you see any exception printed in the console. Maybe, the record after 91 is corrupt(incorrect or missing json key) which causes the exception and exits your 'for' loop

Comment: NO error is printing actually my  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString()); printing a 91 records similarly JSONArray getting a same record..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [Google Gson API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? It may be good choice instead of JSON and you can clearly understand whether the problem with parser or request.

There is a good and simple example [here](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON).